# Series of Geometric Means Converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I'm trying to prove the following:

Let $\{b_{n}\}_{n \ge 1}$ be a sequence of strictly positive terms such that
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}b_{n}$$
converges. Set $\gamma_{n} = (b_{1} \cdots b_{n})^{1/n}$. Prove
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\gamma_{n}$$
converges.

Attempt: Letting $b = \sum b_{n}$, and using AM-GM:
\begin{align*}
            \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}(b_{1} \cdots b_{n})^{\frac{1}{n}} &< \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}b_{1}\cdots b_{n} \\
            &< \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{n}}(b_{1}+\cdots+b_{n})^{n} \\
            &< \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{b}{n}\right)^{n}
        \end{align*}
 This last series converges by the root test, so $\sum\gamma_{n}$ converges by comparison, given $b_{1} \cdots b_{n} \ge 1$ for all $n$. If $b_{1} \cdots b_{n} < 1$ for finite $n$, then we can reduce this case to the previous argument by adding a sufficiently large constant to $\sum(\frac{b}{n})^{n}$. My problem is that I dont know how to deal with the case: $b_{1} \cdots b_{n} < 1$ for infinite $n$...

Comment: Do you have some good reason to think this is actually true?

Comment: Not really, I just know it wouldn't change the series and it seems like an interesting thing to try. I'm working through it now. More of a gut feeling.

Comment: Fine. Might be better to mention that it's a conjecture. lest  people think about proving it but don't consider it might be false. Anyway, what do you mean by "it wouldn't change the series"?

Comment: It's an old homework assignment (post end of class) so its true, not a conjecture. What I mean by "it wouldn't chance the series" is that you're multiplying each term by a disguised 1. So, the sum of the series doesnt chance but I might be able to make the terms look different.

Comment: Not sure if the root test will help much, since $\gamma_n^{1/n} = (b_1 \cdots b_n)^{1/n^2}$ so the root test on $\gamma$ is even stricter than the root test on $b_n$ and just the fact that the series converges doesn't even tell us if $b_n$ passes the root test. While your argument itself is not wrong you're assuming the series converges and that $b_1 \cdots b_n \ge 1$ for all $n$ which is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another variation  of the theme by also introducing  factors to assure the convergence when applying AM-GM.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty}&\color{blue}{\left(b_1b_2\cdots b_n\right)^{1/n}}\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left(b_1c_1b_2c_2\cdots b_nc_n\right)^{1/n}}{\left(c_1c_2\cdots c_n\right)^{1/n}}\tag{1}\\
> &\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{b_1c_1+b_2c_2+\cdots+ b_nc_n}{n\left(c_1c_2\cdots c_n\right)^{1/n}}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_nc_n\sum_{j=n}^\infty\frac{1}{j\left(c_1c_2\cdots c_j\right)^{1/j}}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_nc_n\sum_{j=n}^\infty \frac{1}{j(j+1)}\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\frac{c_n}{n}\tag{5}\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\tag{6}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{\leq e\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n}\tag{7}
> \end{align*}
>
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we introduce factors $c_j$ which we will appropriately set to assure convergence of the series.
- In (2) we apply the AM-GM.
- In (3) we do some rearrangements.
- In (4) we inductively set $(c_1c_2\cdots c_j)^{1/j}=j+1$ which gives us a nicely telescoping series.
- In (5) we use the telescoping property $\sum_{j=n}^\infty\frac{1}{j(j+1)}=\sum_{j=n}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{j}-\frac{1}{j+1}\right)=\frac{1}{n}$.
- In (6) we find $$c_n=\frac{c_1c_2\cdots c_n}{c_1c_2\cdots c_{n-1}}=\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n-1}}=n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$.
- In (7) we use the bound $1+x< e^x$ with $x=\frac{1}{n}, n=1,2,\ldots$.

> *Note:*
>
> - The inequality (7) is known as *[Carleman's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleman%27s_inequality)*.
> - This answer follows the solution of *Problem 2.4* in *[The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052154677X)* by J. M. Steele.

Comment: I really enjoy this solution. In $(7)$ you meant to write $1+x < e^{x}$ with $x = \frac{1}{n}$ though, right? Also, may I ask how you came up with this idea? I would never of thought to do this.

Comment: @Twiss013: Thanks, typo corrected. There are three ingredients which are used. The main theme is AM-GM. The second one are the convergence generating factors, This is a common approach when working with infinite series or products. But it is just a trial without guarantee of success. The third aspect is to set the $c_j$ inductively as in (4) in order to obtain the telescoping sum. This is based on experience and also just a lucky guess. The nice aspect is, that $c_n$ has a convenient form allowing the final estimation in (7).

Comment: Much appreciated! I'll make a note of this, seeing that it's a useful technique and I haven't seen it before. Thanks again!

Comment: @Twiss013: You're welcome. Good to see the answer is useful. :-)

Comment: @Twiss013: Many thanks for accepting my answer and granting the bounty.

Answer (score 8):

Using AM-GM,

$$\gamma_n = \left(\prod_{k=1}^n b_k\right)^{1/n} = \left(\frac{1}{n!}\prod_{k=1}^nkb_k\right)^{1/n} \leqslant \frac{1}{n(n!)^{1/n}}\sum_{k=1}^n k b_k$$

Using the inequality $(n!)^{-1/n} \leqslant e/(n+1)$ (which follows from Stirling's approximation) we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^m \gamma_n \leqslant \sum_{n=1}^m\frac{1}{n(n!)^{1/n}}\sum_{k=1}^n k b_k = \sum_{n=1}^m\frac{1}{n(n!)^{1/n}}\sum_{k=1}^m k b_k \mathbf{1}_{k \leqslant n} \\ = \sum_{k=1}^m b_k k\sum_{n=k}^m\frac{1}{n(n!)^{1/n}} \\\leqslant \sum_{k=1}^m b_k k\sum_{n=k}^m\frac{e}{n(n+1)} \\ \leqslant  \sum_{k=1}^m b_k k\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{e}{n(n+1)} \\= e \sum_{k=1}^mb_k,   $$

and convergence of $\sum b_n$ implies convergence of $\sum \gamma_n$.

Comment: That's clever, but how did you go from $\sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{ke}{n(n+1)}$ to $e$? Seems like it should be something on the order of $e k (\frac{\pi}{6} - \frac1k)$.

Comment: For the inner sum, $k$ is constant. We have the telescoping sum $\sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \sum_{n=k}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} \right) = \frac{1}{k}$

Comment: So $b_k k \sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{e}{n(n+1)} = eb_k$

Comment: Thanks that cleared things up, I didn't notice the telescoping sum.

Comment: @Contravariant: Thanks for checking.

Comment: @RRL how did you get the $(n!)^{-1/n} \leq e/(n+1)$? Thanks!

Comment: @Xiao: That is a relatively well-known inequality related to Stirling's approximation.  [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) we see for all $n$ that $n! \geqslant \sqrt{2 \pi}n^{n +1/2}e^{-n}$. Combining this with $n(\sqrt{2\pi n})^{1/n} > ne^{1/n} > n(1 +1/n) = n+1$ gives us that inequality for $n > 1$. It is obviously true for $n=1$.

Answer (score 2):

You can also prove this using [Hardy's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%27s_inequality):

Set $a_n=\sqrt b_n.$ Then we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2 <\infty.$
Now write

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \gamma_n &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty ((a_1\cdots a_n)^{1/n})^2 \\
&\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\right)^2 \\
&< 4\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2 < \infty.
\end{align}