# Convergence of a series and a series of harmonic means

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ be a decreasing sequence of positive numbers. Assume $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty.$$ Does it imply
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {n\over a_1^{-1}+a_2^{-1}+\ldots +a_n^{-1}}<\infty\ ?$$

Comment: Hint: How is the harmonic mean related to other means and what can you say about the convergence of those means?

Comment: I know only basic staff: the harmonic mean is less or equal the geometric mean, which in turn is less or equal the arithmetic mean.

Comment: Alright. You might find it easier to show something about the convergence of those means.

Comment: For the arithmetic mean the series is obviously divergent. I do not know what happens for the series of the geometric means. I have tested $a_n=n^{-1}\log^{-2}(n+1)$ and the series of geometric means is convergent.

Comment: Why is the arithmetic mean obviously divergent? You shouldn't jump to conclusions until you have found a counterexample

Comment: For the arithmetic mean i.e. ${a_1+\ldots + a_n\over n},$ the $n$-th term of the corresponding series is greater than ${a_1\over n}.$ The series is thus divergent for every positive decreasing sequence $a_n.$

Comment: I don't quite get your argument, but I noticed that I misread the summation sign. It is not in the denominator. You actually have a double sum there, right? If that is the case, my arguments don't necessarily apply, sorry.

Comment: Yes, it is a double sum. I cannot put the arithmetic mean in the denominator, as it tends to 0. So the single term of the series would tend to infinity. I cannot continue  the discussion as I got a notice from the service to move discussion to chat, but I as a beginner I am not entitled to do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133568/discussion-between-ryszard-szwarc-and-manatee-pink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested, looking at the convergence of other means might help. Digging around I have found a Math Stack Exchange post where it is shown that the series of geometric means is convergent for a positive sequence whose partial sums converge

[Series of Geometric Means Converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2857108/series-of-geometric-means-converges)

And since the harmonic means are less than the geometric means, the series of harmonic means has to converge via the comparison test.

Comment: Actually I was after the series of geometric means. It turns out that this series od bounded above by e times the sum of original series, a result od Carleman. Thanks